# Jquery File Upload Blueimp - cancel event (and count total current pre-upload images)

Tags: jquery, html, image, upload, blueimp

I'm using Jquery file upload blueimp (basic plus UI) to upload data,

my concern is with the cancel buttons, eg : when i pre-upload 3 images, and then i cancel all the images so the table row would be empty,
i want to display 'no image chosen' as a default table row (tr) after that action.

i found out the cancel event is in the jquery-fileupload-ui.js.

```
_cancelHandler: function (e) {                  
        e.preventDefault();            
        var template = $(e.currentTarget)
                .closest('.template-upload,.template-download'),
            data = template.data('data') || {};
        data.context = data.context || template;                       

        if (data.abort) {
            data.abort();
        } else {
            data.errorThrown = 'abort';
            this._trigger('fail', e, data);
        }                              
    },
```

how can i know number of pre-upload files, so when the current pre-upload file is empty, i will append html to the table 'no image chosen',

your help will be wonderfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use event fail:

```
$('#TestForm').fileupload({
     dataType : 'json',
     autoUpload : false,
     add : function(e, data) {
         // do something
     },
     fail : function(e, data) {
         // do what do you want when upload canceled or other problem
     }
 )
 });
```